# AMP how to resolve issue of Reduce unused JavaScript google core web vitals

Tags: javascript, facebook, paypal, youtube, addthis

We are using Magento stores, when we are checking the website on google core web vitals it is showing that we need to Reduce unused JavaScript.

How can we reduce this because it is coming from third parties like AddThis, PayPal, youtube, and Facebook?

Please refer to screenshot -
[image]